# C# async, execution stopped, what is going on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Some of the moments I actually know what I am doing; this isn't one of them.

I try to understand why the execution of my code stops the moment I execute a specific async operation. It works when executed synchronously, it doesn't when executed asynchronously.

This all happens in an MVC application;

- `AccountController` creates a new Account, via an `AccountService` to keep my controllers more or less clean.
- In the `AccountService` we do some things like a user account (ASP.NET Identity) and this works fine. Nothing special.
- Then, I try to send an email "Welcome to your new account" and everything goes wrong.

I am not especially looking for a solution, I am more curious as to what is happening.

The moment I execute the await `EmailSender.Send(message);` in the `CreatePrimaryUser` method, the `account.AccountOwnerId = userId;` line is never executed anymore. There is no exception. It looks like everything went fine but the method just stopped executing.

Where did I go wrong?

**AccountController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(AccountViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            BusinessServiceFacade.GetAccountService(RavenMasterSession).Create(model.ToModel(), model.SubscriptionPlanId);
            return Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}.localhost:6257/Admin/GettingStarted",model.Name));
        }
        catch(AccountTakenException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account name already taken");
        }
        catch (CustomException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error:" + e);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**GetAccountService Create**

```
public async Task<Account> Create(Account account, string subscriptionPlanId)
{
    if (IsAccountNameTaken(account.Name))
        throw new AccountTakenException();

    RavenMasterSession.Store(account); // register account in MasterDB
    CreateTenantDatabase(account); // create tenantDB

    var userId = await CreatePrimaryUser(account); // create account owner (first user)
    account.AccountOwnerId = userId;

    var stripeAccountResult = BusinessServiceFacade.GetStripeService(RavenMasterSession).CreateCustomer(account); // register account in Stripe
    account.CustomerId = stripeAccountResult.CustomerId;

    AddSubscription(account, subscriptionPlanId); // add subscription to account

    return account;
}
```

**CreatePrimaryUser**

```
private async Task<string> CreatePrimaryUser(Account account)
{
    var user = new User()
    {
        UserName = account.AccountOwner.Email,
        FirstName = account.AccountOwner.FirstName,
        LastName = account.AccountOwner.LastName,
        Email = account.AccountOwner.Email
    };
    RavenContext.GetTenantSession().Store(user);

    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("recipient@domain.com");
            message.Subject = "Thank you for joining ... ";
            message.Body = string.Format("Your account is available at http://{0}.localhost:6257/Admin/GettingStarted", account.Name);

        await EmailSender.Send(message);
    }
    else
    {
        RavenContext.GetTenantSession().Delete(user);
        var stringList = String.Concat(result.Errors.ToArray());
        throw new CustomException(stringList);
    }
    return user.Id;
}
```

**EmailSender**

```
public static async Task SendSES(MailMessage message)
{
    const string FROM = "from@domain.com";
    message.From = new MailAddress(FROM);

    const string SMTP_USERNAME = "user";   
    const string SMTP_PASSWORD = "pass";  
    const string HOST = "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
    const int PORT = 587;

    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
    {                
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            //client.Send(message);
            await client.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some hints:  Format your code properly.  If you have indent problems, just select the code that's indented improperly and hit ctrl-k.  Click this link and try it now: [edit].  It's often better to get the indentation right in the IDE first then copy it.  Saying "I am not especially looking for a solution," kinda invites downvotes.  You don't have to qualify why you're asking.  You have a deadlock issue and you don't know where, and you are asking for help with it.  That's perfectly fine.  Hinting that you don't really have a problem => wasting people's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a symptom of mixing async sync somewhere which will cause a deadlock exactly as you describe. Change your calling code like below so its async all the way otherwise there is no real benefit to using async. Changing it like this is no problem as you are using MVC which supports this for action signatures.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
// change to async
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(AccountViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var service = BusinessServiceFacade.GetAccountService(RavenMasterSession);

            // broken apart so you can see the await call
            await service.Create(model.ToModel(), model.SubscriptionPlanId);

            return Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}.localhost:6257/Admin/GettingStarted",model.Name));
        }
        catch(AccountTakenException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account name already taken");
        }
        catch (CustomException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error:" + e);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

---

#### Side note 1

To rethrow an exception write only `throw;` and not `throw ex;`. Doing the later resets the call stack in the exception making it difficult to debug later on. To preserve the exception state/call stack use the former (best practice and always recommended)!

```
try {
    // something that could throw exception
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // do something with the exception like logging or retry or whatever
    // if the code does nothing but a rethrow then remove the whole try/catch as it has no added value
    throw;
}
```

#### Side note 2

For non-action methods (those methods not defined on your Mvc or Web API controllers) you should suffix the method with Async as a naming convention if the method is an asynchronous method. This makes it easy to see where in your code you can make use of `await` or some other Task mechanism to execute the code. You can see that Microsoft does this as well with the async methods built into the FCL. It is not required (there is nothing to enforce it) but it is good practice because it makes for more readable code.

- `Create` becomes `CreateAsync`
- `CreatePrimaryUser` becomes `CreatePrimaryUserAsync`
- `SendSES` becomes `SendSESAsync`